# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Import and Export Settings error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to change the color scheme for Microsoft VS 2010, to get a more color-balanced theme for the eyes. According to [this](http://studiostyl.es/home/faq) source, it is a very simple process, one just has to download the appropriate color scheme and install it using

**Tools** -> **Import and Export Settings** -> **Import selected environment settings** ->  **Browse** -> **Choose settings to import** -> **Finish**

However, when I try to click on Tools and Import and Export Settings, I get the following error:

*The type initializer for 'Microsoft.WizardFramework.WizardSettings' threw an exception.*

I tried to google this error, but all I found is a link to some msdn forum, which had this issue unsolved.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out on my own. For my particular case, the problem was in the used system font (which was not the default system font). For some dubious reasons, VS threw back that exception every time. Once I changed back to the default font, the error appeared no more and I was able further to apply the desired theme vs settings. Hope this helps!